# How can I check if a regex matches forever?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a way to check if a regex can match 0 characters, and therefore matches infinitely. For example, the regex `.*` can match 0 characters which means that it will loop for ever, crashing my app.

In my app, the user inputs a regex, which can of course loop forever. How can I prevent this happening?

Comment: You change the regex to make sure it isn't `.*` ?!

Comment: But `.*` isn't the only regex which will match infinitely.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: My app is a regex editor/tester. The user inputs a regex and some text, and it highlights the matches. However, if the user inputs a regex which matches infinitely, the app crashes. I need to prevent this from happening

Comment: So what you are actually asking is "why my app loops forever and crashes?" Add the code and you might be able to get help with that :)

Comment: I know _why_ it's happening - I just need to know how to stop it happening. I was thinking of possibly modifying the regex to make it not loop forever, but I have no idea how.

Comment: I don't think you know  why it's happening, because it shouldn't happen. a `match` on regex should return `true/false`, it **shouldn't loop**. If you have a loop in your app - it's how you programmed it, and it's not related to the regex itself.

Comment: If this were about code in general, then you have discovered the halting problem.

Comment: Would the halting problem be the same in a regex? Would you be able to tell if a regex would halt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a regex matching infinitely; thus being stuck in an infinite loop. As an example, the regex `.*` will stop immediately when there are 0 characters and will run for `n` iterations on any string of `n` characters.

A regex is a form of a finite state machine. A string, its input, is also always finite. There is no infinite in regular expressions.

Here is a the same question asked in a CS context: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47835/can-a-regular-expression-be-infinite

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure that it _will_ loop forever.

Comment: `"Text\nText2".match(new RegExp(".*",'g'))` returns `["Text", "", "Text2", ""]`, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. A regex of `.*` is a FSM that will loop over each element in the string until there are no more elements, thus building up its matched state. Since there are no elements the regex will stop immediately.

Comment: Okay, I've had a look and it turns out that it doesn't crash if I make the regex global. Is it a good idea to always put that onto the user's regex?

Comment: Here is proof: https://regex101.com/r/7EeDig/1. You will see that the regex matched to the empty string. If the regex would loop forever no matched state could ever be returned from the FSM. Think about it.

Comment: Okay, maybe you're right then. My app still crashes, though. Would it be safe to add the g flag to the user's regex, regardless of whether they want to or not?

Comment: Zac, you've asked one question and I've given you one (correct) answer. The fact that your app crashes is due to some other reason you must explore. You can ask another question, but this one has been answered.

Comment: No problem. Good luck